# Why am i getting this timezone error and is there a better way to map between Google Maps Timezone and Windows Time Zones?

Tags: c#, datetime, google-maps-api-3, timezone

I have the following code to Convert from location to TimeZone name.

```
public TimeZoneResponse ConvertCityToTimeZoneName(string location)
{
   TimeZoneResponse response = new TimeZoneResponse();
   var plusName = location.Replace(" ", "+");
   var address = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + plusName + "&sensor=false";
   var result = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(address);
   var latLongResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleGeoCodeResponse>(result);

   if (latLongResult.status == "OK")
   {
       var timeZoneRespontimeZoneRequest = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=" + latLongResult.results[0].geometry.location.lat + "," + latLongResult.results[0].geometry.location.lng + "&timestamp=1362209227&sensor=false";
       var timeZoneResponseString = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(timeZoneRespontimeZoneRequest);
       var timeZoneResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TimeZoneResult>(timeZoneResponseString);

       if (timeZoneResult.status == "OK")
       {

           response.TimeZoneName = timeZoneResult.timeZoneName;
           response.Success = true;
           return response;
       }
   }
   return response;
```

}

So when I pass in "New York, United States", it returns "Eastern Standard Time"

I then have this second functions that converts a time from one source timezone into this other retrieved timezone above.

```
var timeInDestTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(sourceDate.Date, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, destination.TimeZoneName);
```

Its works well until i ran into this example.  When I pass in: **Melbourne, Australia** into the first function I get back: **Australian Eastern Daylight Time**

When I pass Australian Eastern Daylight Time into my second function (as the final argument), I get this error back:

**The time zone ID 'Australian Eastern Daylight Time' was not found on the local computer**

Any suggestions on what i am doing wrong?  When i look at the response from second google maps API call these are all of the fields that i get back (using LA as an example):

```
{
 "dstOffset" : 0.0,
 "rawOffset" : -28800.0,
 "status" : "OK",
 "timeZoneId" : "America/Los_Angeles",
 "timeZoneName" : "Pacific Standard Time"
}
```

When I pass in Melbourne,I see the TimeZoneId field is set to : ""Australia/Hobart"".  Is that the right field to look at for the timezone calculation. Or should I be looking at the other "offset" fields?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have badges almost as Jon Skeet... :)

Comment: This can be done now with Noda Time 1.1.0.  [I have posted conversion functions here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17348807/634824)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to how .NET implements Time Zones, there's no built-in way to do a `1:1` conversion. You will have to resort to using 3rd party libraries (or implement your own conversion).

---

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084246/get-windows-timezoneinfo-from-latitude-and-longitude) asks for a very similar solution to what you are looking for.

The asker found a solution by using the [Olson Time Zone Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) (*tz database/zoneinfo database/IANA Time Zone Database*) internally. The asker references a [page](http://www.timdavis.com.au/data/olson-time-zone-database-to-standard-windows-time-zone-v01/) which explains a bit about the conversion.

---

Lastly, you can use [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/), which implements this very functionality you are looking for. Jon Skeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7084290/238722) gives an early look at the library's development back in 2011.

The library's [Key Concepts page](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/wiki/KeyConcepts) contains a [Date/Time Zone](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/wiki/KeyConcepts#DateTimeZone) block explaining the conversion functionality.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15038661/238722) on how to create such a *lookup table*:

```cs
// Note: this version lets you work with any IDateTimeZoneSource, although as the only
// other built-in source is BclDateTimeZoneSource, that may be less useful :)
private static IDictionary<string, string> LoadTimeZoneMap(IDateTimeZoneSource source)
{
    var nodaToWindowsMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var bclZone in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
    {
        var nodaId = source.MapTimeZoneId(bclZone);
        if (nodaId != null)
        {
            nodaToWindowsMap[nodaId] = bclZone.Id;
        }
    }
    return nodaToWindowsMap;
}
```

Comment: The link I gave is to Olson as well.  Your answer is much more suited to the OP's situation. +1

Answer (score 1):

100%? then use standard timezone names to validate:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
```

If the timezone is not found on the given machine there is NO GUARANTEED WORKAROUND.  You should have your code create an error message stating why there was a problem.

You do realize that it is possible for the owner/admin of a given system to change those settings, or add new ones - meaning non-standard tz names not in the tz database.

Comment: I don't have any control of the input info bits coming from a persons contact info that i don't have control over